# reading real time data using a serial port ,plotting it on a graph and saving it to an excel file

Tags: c#, arduino

I am plotting a real time chart from a serial port. I then wish to press the stop button.This is when the chart readings halt. Then, when I press the save button, I want the values plotted on the graph till then to be saved in an excel sheet.

Till now, I am able to achieve my goal till stop button, but I am stuck on the saving to the excel sheet part. Can some one help me out?

And I am using a windows form application in visual Studio 2015 plus I am taking two sensor values from the serial port.

```
 private void showchart(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        readings.Add(sensor.Substring(4,3));
        readings.Add(sensor.Substring(10,3));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sensor.Substring(4, 3),sensor.Substring(10,3));

        chart1.Series["test1"].Points.AddXY(0, sensor.Substring(4, 3));
        chart1.Series["test2"].Points.AddXY(0, sensor.Substring(10, 3));

        if 
            ((chart1.Series["test1"].Points.Count > 20) && (chart1.Series["test2"].Points.Count > 20))
        {
            chart1.Series["test1"].Points.RemoveAt(0);
            chart1.Series["test2"].Points.RemoveAt(0);
        }
        chart1.Series["test1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
        chart1.Series["test1"].Color = Color.DarkOrange;
        chart1.Series["test2"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
        chart1.Series["test2"].Color = Color.DarkMagenta;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myport.Close();
        myport.BaudRate = 9600;
        myport.PortName = "COM8";
        myport.Open();
        string sensor = myport.ReadLine();

        try
        {
            string pathfile = @"C: \Users\Raman\Desktop\Real Data\";
            string filename = "real data.txt";
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(pathfile + filename,FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter s = new StreamWriter(fs);
            for (int i = 0; i < readings.Count/2; i++)
            {
                s.WriteLine("A="+readings[2*i] + "\t" +"B="+ readings[2*i+1]);
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Data has been saved to" + pathfile,"Save File");

        }
```

Comment: it saves only one value from the graph at that very instant, not all the data which is displayed till then.

Comment: ive uploaded the updated code..plz have a look.

Comment: `readings` is `List<string>` and button_2 is your save button? if so explain what you do expect as an outcome but isn't there. It is still unclear what is wrong between what you expect to happen and actual happens, try to [edit] that in your question: I expected  [the actual numbers you expect].... but instead the output is [ the numbers you really get]

Comment: yes,readings is List<string> and button_2 is save button.Step-1->when i press start button, graph starts to plot the real time data.Step-2->when i press the stop button , the graph pauses.Step-3->When i press the save button, i want all the values plotted on the graph to be saved in an excel sheet.  I HAVE SUCCEEDED TILL STEP-2 BUT [when i press the save button only reading from the graph is saving ]....Eg. i want       A=456 B=914
A=458 B=913
A=456 B=910
A=455 B=910
A=453 B=913                               but i get A=453 B=913    .

Comment: Is it maybe because you're closing and re-opening the serial port. If you put a breakpoint on the first line in button_2_click, how many items are there in `readings`?

Comment: it worked ..i altered the stream writer  code a  bit...thanks though!!

Comment: can u help me save this data in an excel sheet?....currently i am able to save it in a text document..

Comment: Excel reads CSV files so if you format your output like that you're all set. Otherwise look into OpenXML

Comment: thank you , you've been a great help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a Data Transfer Object (DTO) to hold the info you need per row. In this case your class could look like this:

```
public class Reading
{
     public string A {get; set;}
     public string B {get; set;}
     public DateTime CreationDate {get;set;}
}
```

Your current `List<string> readings = new List<string>()` should become `Reading readings = new List<Reading>();` and your `ShowChart` needs to be adapted to use that new DTO.

```
private void showchart(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var reading = new Reading{ 
        A = sensor.Substring(4,3),
        B = sensor.Substring(10,3),
        CreationDate = DateTime.Now
    };

    readings.Add(reading);

    var test1Series =  chart1.Series["test1"];
    var test2Series =  chart1.Series["test2"];

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
         "{0} {1} {2}", 
        reading.A,
        reading.B,
        reading.CreationDate);

    test1Series.Points.AddXY(0, reading.A);
    test2Series.Points.AddXY(0, reading.B);

    if ((test1Series.Points.Count > 20) && 
        (test2Series.Points.Count > 20))
    {
        test1Series.Points.RemoveAt(0);
        test2Series.Points.RemoveAt(0);
    }
    // you only need this once, consider moving it to an init method
    test1Series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
    test1Series.Color = Color.DarkOrange;
    test2Series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
    test2Series.Color = Color.DarkMagenta;
}
```

The your `button2_click` will need to be changed to read the `Reading` objects from `readings` and write it to the CSV file. Notice I used [string formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) to shape your output. I also added using statements to properly close and dispose the stream and filehandle used for writing to the file.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string pathfile = @"C:\Users\Raman\Desktop\Real Data\";
        string filename = "Data.csv";
        using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(
            Path.Combine(pathfile, filename), 
            FileMode.Append, 
            FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using(StreamWriter s = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
              foreach(var reading in readings)
              {
                 // format the output
                 s.WriteLine(
                   "{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss},{1},{2}",
                   reading.CreationDate,
                   reading.A,
                   reading.B
                 );
              }
            }
           MessageBox.Show("Data has been saved to" + pathfile,"Save File");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception exp) 
    {
         MessageBox.Show(exp.Message,"Error");
    }
}
```

When you run this you will see in your data file:

> `2016-06-18 09:06:56,ValueFromA,ValueFromB`
>     `2016-06-18 09:18:39,AnotherValueFromA,AnotherValueFromB`

Comment: readings.Add(reading); ....it says that it does not contain the definition for add

Comment: @dartagnan `readings` has to be a `List<Reading>`. A list does have an Add method ...

Comment: i am receiving the values from serial port as--*s1=0371s2=0854s3=0892s4=0419s5=0912s6=0439s7=0932s8=0469s9=0932s10=0469s11=0932s12=0469# ,,,,,,,i had to save the int values to excel ..it works good except that the values saved in excel don't include the 0 in thousandth place...............although my code commands to save all the four digits.....i.e. i receive 0123,,,i set the string length to be saved to 4,,,but the value saved is 123......I DONT UNDERSTAND WHY?

Comment: If it is a number Excel removes the 0, that is a *feature*. If you don't want that to happen you can enclose the *number* in double quotes,  like so `"0123"` but Excel wouldn't treat it as a number any longer so you can't do calculations with it in Excel.

Comment: thanks for the explanation,,,if i want the code to start loading the values only after it discovers a " * " ,,any help??     i mean if the readings start loading from somewhere in between the whole string ,,i want to store the readings only after it discovers the  next " * "(asterix)

Comment: I think it is time for you to ask a new question so you can prevent to become [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire). Make sure to prepare your question, including your attempt, by following the advice in [the question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: it is the final phase of my project ,,if u could help me one last time?

Comment: Nope, detecting a * in a stream is easy, you can work that out on your own, or ask a new question as I said.